# Adding headers to Django EmailMultiAlternatives

Tags: python, django, email, header, smtp

In [Django EmailMultiAlternatives documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/email/) there is nothing about how to add headers like "format" or "Reply-To" in `EmailMultiAlternatives`. It took a while for me to figure it out and I am sending this post to help others with saving their time.

As you can see in django's source code, `EmailMultiAlternatives` inherits from `EmailMessage`, so they take the same parameters in the init constructor. This way, we can add headers like:

```
msg = EmailMultiAlternatives(
    subject, message, from_email, to_list,
    headers={'Reply-To': "email@example.com", 'format': 'flowed'}
)
```

Comment: You should write this as a solution.

Comment: @VanniTotaro I appreciate your suggestion and I know I can get more reputation by answering questions, but when I can make it as a single concise post, why should I divide it into two longer posts and waste others' time?

Comment: Well, first of all this question would become "answered", or else if I'm in search of an answer I could end skipping this one because apparently it is an unanswered question. Moreover I think that rules here discourage this Q+A post pattern. BTW thank you, because I made use of your nice solution.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267434/what-is-the-appropriate-action-when-the-answer-to-a-question-is-added-to-the-que

Answer (score 2):

Back in 2015 OP complained, that there were no instructions in documentation, how to add headers such as "Format" and "Reply-To" in Django mail (django.core.mail) module. However today, while using [same documentation link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/email/). We can find description and examples in 2018 easily:

> *class* **`EmailMessage`**[[source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/core/mail/message/#EmailMessage)]
>
> The **EmailMessage** *class* is initialized with the following parameters
>   (*in the given order, if positional arguments are used*). All parameters
>   are optional and can be set at any time prior to calling the **`send()`**
>   method.
>
> - **subject**: The subject line of the email.
> - **body**: The body text. This should be a plain text message.
> - **from_email**: The sender’s address. Both **`fred@example.com`** and **`Fred <fred@example.com>`** forms are legal. If omitted, the **`DEFAULT_FROM_EMAIL`**
>     setting is used.
> - **to**: A list or tuple of recipient addresses.
> - **bcc**: A list or tuple of addresses used in the “Bcc” header when sending the email.
> - **connection**: An email backend instance. Use this parameter if you want to use the same connection for multiple messages. If omitted, a
>     new connection is created when **`send()`** is called.
> - **attachments**: A list of attachments to put on the message. These can be either **`email.MIMEBase.MIMEBase`** instances, or **`(filename, content, mimetype)`** triples.
> - **headers**: A dictionary of extra headers to put on the message. The keys are the header name, values are the header values. It’s up to the
>     caller to ensure header names and values are in the correct format for
>     an email message. The corresponding attribute is `extra_headers`.
> - **cc**: A list or tuple of recipient addresses used in the “Cc” header when sending the email.
>
> For example:
>
> ```
> email = EmailMessage('Hello', 'Body goes here', 'from@example.com',
>             ['to1@example.com', 'to2@example.com'], ['bcc@example.com'],
>             headers = {'Reply-To': 'another@example.com', 'format': 'flowed'})
> ```

As we see from examples, `EmailMessage` has `headers` argument (*dictionary*) too, `EmailMultiAlternatives` according to docstring in [source code](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/_modules/django/core/mail/message/#EmailMessage) is:

```
A version of EmailMessage that makes it easy to send multipart/alternative
messages. For example, including text and HTML versions of the text is
made easier.
```

So if you don't need something specific, `EmailMessage` is fine, because currently `EmailMultiAlternatives` is for easy inclusion of text and HTML versions of text.